# Selecting Dispatchers in CoroutineScope

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin

Having this example code:

```
private fun exampleFunc() {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.??).launch {
        exampleFunc1()
        exampleFunc2()
    }
}

private suspend fun exampleFunc1(): Int = withContext(Dispatchers.Main)  {
    //Long code
    return@withContext 0
}

private suspend fun exampleFunc2(): Int = withContext(Dispatchers.IO)  {
    //Long code
    return@withContext 0
}
```

exampleFunc1 will run on Main and exampleFunc2 will run on IO. But CoroutineScope requres me to choose a Dispatcher, and there is no option to leave it empty like in GlobalScope.launch. What is your recommendation in this case?

Comment: In general, it is not recommended to use GlobalScope and unbound CoroutineScope, instead it is preferable to use Scope bound with some object with a predictable lifecycle. In your example you can replace CoroutineScope with GlobalScope and get the same result. For CoroutineScope you can choose any Dispatcher but if your function perform any operations with UI, use Dispatchers.Main or Default.

Comment: `CoroutineScope()` doesn't require you to specify the dispatcher. You can skip it and then by default it uses `Dispatchers.Default`. But for some reason which I don't understand, it requires some coroutine context. You can pass `EmptyCoroutineContext` if you don't want to specify the dispatcher, but this is pretty much the same as passing `Dispatchers.Default`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be creating one-off CoroutineScopes to launch a single coroutine anyway. That's what GlobalScope is for, and it should be avoided because you normally care about when something is going out of its lifecycle of usefulness and should therefore be released/cancelled.

I don't know for sure why the `CoroutineScope()` function doesn't allow you to leave it blank so it will use `EmptyCoroutineContext` (and therefore `Dispatchers.Default`). But maybe they figured you would at minimum want to be giving its context a `CoroutineName` for logging and exception message purposes.

Suspend functions should always internally use `withContext` if they cannot accept being run on any arbitrary dispatcher, so ultimately it won't matter what dispatcher is being used in the calling code. In your example code, the coroutine is only calling suspend functions, so there will be no difference in behavior, no matter which dispatcher you choose.

If the root coroutines that you call in this scope are touching things that can only be touched on the main thread, then in makes sense to use `Dispatchers.Main` as your default context in the CoroutineScope.